# 'continue not in loop' error while trying to add an error handling mechanism

Tags: python, loops, except

I've been trying to add an error handling mechanism to my code section. However when it runs it says 'continue outside of loop' but looking at the code it should be inside the try loop. What's going wrong?

```
def download_media_item(self, entry):
    try:
        url, path = entry
        # Get the file extension example: ".jpg"
        ext = url[url.rfind('.'):]
        if not os.path.isfile(path + ext):
            r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=15)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                open(path + ext, 'wb').write(r.content)
                self.user_log.info('File {} downloaded from {}'.format(path, url))
                return True
            elif r.status_code == 443:
                print('------------the server reported a 443 error-----------')
                return False
        else:
            self.user_log.info('File {} already exists. URL: {}'.format(path, url))
            return False
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Received ConnectionError. Retrying...")
        continue
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        print("Received ReadTimeout. Retrying...")
        continue
```

Comment: You have no `for` loop.

Comment: Your `continue` statements are not inside any loop. Are you saying that there is a `for` loop somewhere?

Comment: What `for` loop? Both of the `continue` statements in your `except` cases are outside of a loop

Comment: You don't need `continue` to continue execution following the `try` statement; that already happens. For example, omitting `continue` from `except requests.ConnectionError` does not cause the `except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout` block to execute next.

Comment: I meant the try loop. I was aiming to have it retry the exact same URL that caused the error. from googling around it seemed like an except could work in a try loop, but should I change it to a for loop?

Comment: Do or do not, there is no `try loop`.

Comment: @Aedam A `try` block will be tried once only. If you need it to loop then you have to put it inside a loop.

Comment: @quamrana has already said this in a somewhat oblique manner, but I think it is worth stating explicitly: Some people seem to call all compound statement "loops", and talk about things like an "if loop" or a "try loop", or even a "def loop". This is simply incorrect terminology. Loops are things that repeat. `if` and `try` statements are just (compound) statements.

Comment: @TurePålsson: Ok, this is news to me, but I'll try to be more explicit in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that what you are actually wanting to do is keep looping until no exception is raised.

In general, you can do this by having an infinite loop that you break from in the event of a successful completion.

Either:

```
while True:
    try:
        # do stuff
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        # handle error
        continue
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        # handle error
        continue
    break
```

Or:

```
while True:
    try:
        # do stuff
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        # handle error
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        # handle error
    else:
        break
```

However, in this case, the "do stuff" seems to always end by reaching a `return` statement, so the `break` is not required, and the following reduced version would suffice:

```
while True:
    try:
        # do stuff
        return some_value
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        # handle error
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        # handle error
```

(The single `return` shown here may refer to alternative control flows, all of which lead to a `return`, as in your case.)

Comment: I don't think the OP needs any `break` specifically since their current code always seems to have a `return` path if there is no exception. Anyway, its a +1 from me.

Comment: @quamrana Good point, thank you. I didn't look closely enough at the details of the "do stuff" in this case. I'll add your observation as a note at the end, but in terms of possible more generic use I think I'll leave the answer otherwise as-is.

Comment: @quamrana Now updated to reflect this. Thanks again for the observation.

Answer (score 2):

`continue` is *specifically* for immediately moving to the next iteration of a `for` or `while` loop; it is not an all-purpose move-to-the-next-statement instruction.

In a `try`/`except` statement, anytime you reach the end of a `try`, `except`, `else`, or `finally` block, execution proceeds with the next complete statement, not the next portion of the `try` statement.

```
def download_media_item(self, entry):
    # 1: try statement
    try:
        ...
        # If you get here, execution goes to #2 below, not the
        # except block below
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Received ConnectionError. Retrying...")
        # Execution goes to #2 below, not the except block below
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        print("Received ReadTimeout. Retrying...")
        # Execution goes to #2 below

    # 2: next statement
    ...
```